# Can a Formal Concept Lattice Have two Empty Sets?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $G=\{cat,apple\}$ and $M=\{Meows,Fruit\}$

then

$C(G,M,I) = \{(\emptyset,\{Meows,Fruit\}), (\{Cat\},\{Meows\}),(\{Apple\},\{Fruit\}),(\{Cat,Apple\},\emptyset)\}$

And the lattice looks like this with the empty set on top and bottom. Is this allowed?

[image]

Update: I thought about it more last night, and I guess it depends on if you are showing the intent or extent on the lattice. If we we write the intents, the second empty will become {Cat,Apple} instead

Comment: What is an order?  If $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$ what does *antisymmetry* have to say about $x$ and $y$?  If $x\preceq y$ and $x\neq y$ what does that say about whether or not $y\preceq x$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I am unfamiliar with order, antisymmetry, and this notation of $x\preceq y$ could you please help me out?

Comment: what's a formal concept lattice and what's $I$ ?

Comment: The "empties" aren't the same, as you pointed out.  The topmost node of the lattice has all the objects and no attributes (since no attribute is possessed by all the objects).  Its intent is empty and its extent is maximal.  The bottommost node has all the attributes and no objects (since no object shares all those attributes).  Its extent is empty and its intent is maximal.

Comment: @mercio A formal concept lattice is a hierarchical way to represent two sets (a set of objects and a set of attributes). The incidence relation is a binary relation that tells if an object HAS a an attribute. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis

Comment: @mjqxxxx Okay. So I guess that it is acceptable. If you write that up I will accept as answer